# Failed to start Derby database when accessing from JAR

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, derby

I'm trying to query an embedded Derby database located inside a JAR file I created. I believe the program is successfully able to locate the database, however it just fails to start. I know Derby supports accessing a database located inside a JAR because Apache provides [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdeploy11201.html#cdevdeploy11201) on this. I have followed their instructions, but still this error persists.

Every time I try to query said DB, I receive this error code:

```
C:\Development\jdk-17\bin\java.exe -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\lib\idea_rt.jar=64482:C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.7.2\junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Projects\Java\employee-tax-service\target\test-classes;C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Projects\Java\employee-tax-service\target\classes;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.6\spring-boot-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.6\logback-classic-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.6\logback-core-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.5\jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.5\jackson-annotations-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.5\jackson-core-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.12\spring-web-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.12\spring-beans-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.12\spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.12\spring-aop-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.12\spring-context-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.12\spring-expression-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-test-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.5.6\spring-boot-test-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.5.6\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.5.0\json-path-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.7\json-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.4.7\accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.1\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.19.0\assertj-core-3.19.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest\2.2\hamcrest-2.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter\5.7.2\junit-jupiter-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.7.2\junit-jupiter-api-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.2.0\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.7.2\junit-platform-commons-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.7.2\junit-jupiter-params-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.7.2\junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.7.2\junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\3.9.0\mockito-core-3.9.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.10.22\byte-buddy-agent-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.2\objenesis-3.2.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\3.9.0\mockito-junit-jupiter-3.9.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.0\jsonassert-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.12\spring-core-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.12\spring-jcl-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.3.12\spring-test-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.8.3\xmlunit-core-2.8.3.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derby\10.15.2.0\derby-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbyshared\10.15.2.0\derbyshared-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbytools\10.15.2.0\derbytools-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.8\gson-2.8.8.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.database.TestQueryDB,queryDB
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/embedded-db.jar)employees' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Util.java:252)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2855)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(EmbedConnection.java:411)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:660)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(InternalDriver.java:654)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:967)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:136)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.database.TestQueryDB.queryDB(TestQueryDB.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/embedded-db.jar)employees' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(SQLExceptionFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:75)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB2: Unknown container format at container null : 0
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:295)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeaderFromArray(FileContainer.java:796)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeader(FileContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.InputStreamContainer.openContainer(InputStreamContainer.java:92)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdent(FileContainer.java:379)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdentity(FileContainer.java:361)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(ConcurrentCache.java:318)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(BaseDataFileFactory.java:690)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(BaseDataFileFactory.java:620)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.Xact.openContainer(Xact.java:1355)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapConglomerateFactory.readConglomerate(HeapConglomerateFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.CacheableConglomerate.setIdentity(CacheableConglomerate.java:108)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(ConcurrentCache.java:318)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.conglomCacheFind(RAMAccessManager.java:474)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findConglomerate(RAMTransaction.java:401)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findExistingConglomerate(RAMTransaction.java:380)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.openScan(RAMTransaction.java:1558)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.openScan(PropertyConglomerate.java:233)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.readDbProperties(PropertyConglomerate.java:720)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getCachedDbProperties(PropertyConglomerate.java:755)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getCachedProperty(PropertyConglomerate.java:564)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getProperty(PropertyConglomerate.java:632)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PC_XenaVersion.upgradeIfNeeded(PC_XenaVersion.java:61)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.<init>(PropertyConglomerate.java:168)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(RAMAccessManager.java:1175)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2002)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:538)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:48)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:460)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(BasicDatabase.java:1001)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(BasicDatabase.java:995)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(BasicDatabase.java:777)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(BasicDatabase.java:186)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2002)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(BaseMonitor.java:1830)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(BaseMonitor.java:1696)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(BaseMonitor.java:1529)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(BaseMonitor.java:999)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Monitor.java:598)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(EmbedConnection.java:4042)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(EmbedConnection.java:4038)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(EmbedConnection.java:4036)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2816)
    ... 76 more
```

I'm not sure sure what the error means by `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoader...`

Here is my code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM employees";

    @Test
    void queryDB() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:jar:(C:/summer2021/embedded-db.jar)employees")) {
            RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = factory.createCachedRowSet();

            cachedRowSet.setCommand(query);
            cachedRowSet.execute(connection);

            while (cachedRowSet.next()) {
                System.out.print(cachedRowSet.getString("id") + " ");
                System.out.print(cachedRowSet.getFloat("salary") + " ");
                System.out.println(cachedRowSet.getString("filingStatus"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to use a read-only databases within a jar file. Please note, that you have to do some steps in advance to create an existing database and place this into the jar. See documentation parent chapter step 1. Can you verify, that you followed this steps, too.

Comment: Try running `jar tf C:/summer2021/embedded-db.jar` and include the output, that might have some clues about whether your jar format is correct.

Comment: I managed to correctly access the database from within a jar (I made it so that only the database exists inside the jar), but I'm running into a different problem now.